# Автоматическая кастомизация заголовка исходящих запросов nestJS

Tags: api, авторизация, backend, nestjs

Я разрабатываю приложение на nestjs. Внутри него приходится взаимодействовать со сторонним api. и каждый раз добавлять один и тот же заголовок авторизации, как добавлять его автоматический, через HTTPмодуль или через интерцетор?